# How to convert JSF date to MySQL date?

Tags: mysql, date, jsf-2

In JSF I am saving a date to database, but in database the value is different. Everytime it is showing month as `01`. I've already set the context parameter

```
javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE
```

to `true`, but it is still not working. In entity bean I am using `java.util.Date` to hold the date. I am using MySQL as database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you're only taking year-month-day and you incorrectly used `mm` instead of `MM` to denote the month part in the `<f:convertDateTime pattern>` attribute. The `mm` stands for minutes, not months. You can find an overview of all valid patterns in [the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

That context parameter is totally unrelated to the months. It just tells JSF that it should use platform default time zone instead of UTC to use to interpret and represent the time part.

Comment: thanks a lot. i didn,t noticed it such a silly mistake i was doing.. again thanks.

i have one more question 
if i close my browser without logging out form the application i want session to get invalidate. how can i do this in my application?